# Rock Paper Scissors game with counter

Tags: python, counter, wing-ide

```
import random

def main():
playagain = 1
win=0
lose=0
tie=0      
while playagain==1:
    printCpu=cpuConverter()
    printPlayer=playerConverter()
    print("The computers choice is", printCpu)
    print("Your choice is", printPlayer)
    gameWinner(printCpu, printPlayer)
    winner(gameWinner, printCpu, printPlayer)
    playagain=int(input("Would you like to play again? Enter 1 for yes, any other number for no!"))

print("Your total wins are", win)
print("Your total losses are", lose)
print("Your total ties are", tie)



def cpuConverter():
    cpuChoice=random.randrange(1,4)
    if cpuChoice==1:
        printCpu="Rock"
    elif cpuChoice==2:
        printCpu="Paper"
    else:
        printCpu="Scissors"
    return printCpu

def playerConverter():
    again=0
    while again<1 or again>3:
        printPlayer=int(input("Please choose a number to play against the      computer. 1=Rock 2=Paper 3=Scissors "))
        if printPlayer<1 or printPlayer>3:
            print("Invalid choice for the game. Please choose another number inside the constraints.")
        elif printPlayer==1:
            printPlayer="Rock"
            again=1
        elif printPlayer==2:
            printPlayer="Paper"
            again=1
        else:
            printPlayer="Scissors"
            again=1
    return printPlayer

def gameWinner(printCpu, printPlayer):
    if printCpu == printPlayer:
        winner = "tie"
        print("It's a tie")
    elif printCpu == "Scissors" and printPlayer == "Rock":
        winner = "win"
        print("Rock beats Scissors! You win")
    elif printCpu == "Paper" and printPlayer == "Scissors":
        winner = "win"
        print("Scissors cuts paper! You win")
    elif printCpu == "Rock" and printPlayer == "Paper":
        winner = "win"
        print("Paper covers Rock! You win")
    else:
        winner = "lose"
        print("You lose")
    return winner

def winner(gameWinner, printCpu, printPlayer):     
    if winner == "win":
        win += 1
    elif winner == "lose":
        lose += 1
    elif winner == "tie":
        tie += 1
    return winner

main()
```

So when I try this code, everything works for the most part. The only thing I can't seem to get working is the actual counting part. When I try to print my results after playing multiple (or even one) times, the code still ends up with zero as the total amount of games. Can someone please show me where I'm messing up and hopefully help me fix this?

Comment: You've messed variables and functions names

Comment: Why do you return winner in "winner" and also in gameWinner ? Why your function name is the same as the variable "winner" ? I think the first thing to do would be to name your functions with a name that shows precisely what it does.

Answer (score 0):

You have several errors in your code. The first is

```
winner(gameWinner, printCpu, printPlayer)
```

passes a `function` to the function `winner`. You should capture the return value of `gameWinner` and pass it to `winner`

```
result = gameWinner(printCpu, printPlayer)
winner(result, printCpu, printPlayer)
```

Next issue

```
def winner(gameWinner, printCpu, printPlayer):     
    if winner == "win":
```

You are ignoring your input parameters and comparing the `function` itself to the string "win". It will always be `False`. The upshot of this is that your `win`, `lose`, `tie` variables are never touched.

The final issue is that `win`, `lose` and `tie` are global. All experienced programmers frown upon the use of globals, but if you must use them you should firstly declare the variables in the global scope, not inside the function main. You should then should use the `global` keyword inside any function that references them. So inside `winner` we need

```
global win, lose, tie
```

The minimally corrected code looks like

```
import random

win=0
lose=0
tie=0 

def main():
    playagain = 1     
    while playagain==1:
        printCpu=cpuConverter()
        printPlayer=playerConverter()
        print("The computers choice is", printCpu)
        print("Your choice is", printPlayer)
        result = gameWinner(printCpu, printPlayer)
        winner(result, printCpu, printPlayer)
        playagain=int(input("Would you like to play again? Enter 1 for yes, any other number for no!"))

    print("Your total wins are", win)
    print("Your total losses are", lose)
    print("Your total ties are", tie)



def cpuConverter():
    cpuChoice=random.randrange(1,4)
    if cpuChoice==1:
        printCpu="Rock"
    elif cpuChoice==2:
        printCpu="Paper"
    else:
        printCpu="Scissors"
    return printCpu

def playerConverter():
    again=0
    while again<1 or again>3:
        printPlayer=int(input("Please choose a number to play against the      computer. 1=Rock 2=Paper 3=Scissors "))
        if printPlayer<1 or printPlayer>3:
            print("Invalid choice for the game. Please choose another number inside the constraints.")
        elif printPlayer==1:
            printPlayer="Rock"
            again=1
        elif printPlayer==2:
            printPlayer="Paper"
            again=1
        else:
            printPlayer="Scissors"
            again=1
    return printPlayer

def gameWinner(printCpu, printPlayer):
    if printCpu == printPlayer:
        winner = "tie"
        print("It's a tie")
    elif printCpu == "Scissors" and printPlayer == "Rock":
        winner = "win"
        print("Rock beats Scissors! You win")
    elif printCpu == "Paper" and printPlayer == "Scissors":
        winner = "win"
        print("Scissors cuts paper! You win")
    elif printCpu == "Rock" and printPlayer == "Paper":
        winner = "win"
        print("Paper covers Rock! You win")
    else:
        winner = "lose"
        print("You lose")
    return winner

def winner(gameWinner, printCpu, printPlayer):  
    global win, lose, tie   
    if gameWinner == "win":
        win += 1
    elif gameWinner == "lose":
        lose += 1
    elif gameWinner == "tie":
        tie += 1
    return winner

main()
```